# How to add big image as overlay in latest MapBox version(v3.2.2)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, mapbox

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149988/how-can-i-add-one-big-image-as-an-overlay-in-mapbox) that it's possible to add big custom image as part of MapBox.

But now i'm trying to find out how it can be implemented in latest SDK version, and it's seems like there is no such option.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  You will need to modify your own [Mapbox GL Style](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/).

One way to do it is from **Klokantech**
This project from [github.com/klokantech](https://github.com/klokantech/osm2vectortiles-ios/blob/master/OSM2VectorTiles/bright-v8-local.json) can show you how to structure your Mapbox GL Style.

**Mapbox** also has some great resources
Option 1 — upload your raster to [Mapbox Studio](http://Mapbox.com/studio)
Option 2 - Please check out the example from Mapbox.  [Custom raster style.  Use legacy raster tiles on a map.](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/raster-styles/)

This screen cap gives an example of how I've done it in the past for iOS.  This example serves up local PNG's in an iOS app.

[image: Example with custom Mapbox GL Style]

Comment: Hi, In Style `source` of Root properties, Are You using `type` as `image` `"sources": {
  "type": "image",
  "url": "/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif",
  "coordinates": [
      [-80.425, 46.437],
      [-71.516, 46.437],
      [-71.516, 37.936],
      [-80.425, 37.936]
  ]
}`,

If possible can you provide me some source code, that will clear my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: @iNasir — For basic Mapbox GL Style see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411025/how-to-add-own-tile-in-mapbox-4-1/40412786#40412786

Answer (score 0):

If you’re looking to place a geo-rectified image onto a map, that [isn’t possible yet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1350) with the Mapbox iOS SDK.

Using annotations for this purpose (view-based or GL-based) [isn’t quite supported yet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2528), either. Once view-based annotations completely support flatness and ignore map rotation, that may be an adequate workaround. Look for those features in v3.3.0+.